# Simulate DirectoryIndext with RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache

I need to make a RewriteRule that can rewrite:

```
site.com or site.com/
```

to:

```
site.com/file.xx
```

Really not sure how to write this and make it work properly. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) and be prepared to answer questions like "What have you tried?" before posting questions here on Stack Overflow. I think you'll find that this answer either resolves your problem, or at least gives you a good point at which to start.

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /file.ext [R=301,L]
```